# Joining tables with different names

Tags: mysql, sql

As you can see below I'm trying to combine two tables. Both tables display their data a little differently from each other, but not so different that we can't join them.

For the sake of completeness, we will call the tables by their color names:

Red Table will be `red`
Blue Table will be `blue`

From both tables, we will be combining `ID`s
From the `red` table, we will combine `Name` with `blue` table's `Title`
From the `red` table, we will combine `Prod` with `blue` table's `Item`
From the `red` table, we will add `Cost`

I want to know if we can join these two tables and output the results using SQL. In other words, I don't want to create a whole new table, I just want to use a single query to output the combination of both tables.

[image]

When I try to do this, I am getting something like this:

```
ID    Name    Prod    Cost    ID    Title    Item
0     asdf    item1   4.00    1     fdsa     item2
2     sdfg    item3   5.00    3     gfds     item4
4     dfgh    item5   4.00    5     hgfd     item6
```

But I would like to get this:

```
ID    Name    Item    Cost
0     asdf    item1   4.00
1     fdsa    item2
2     sdfg    item3   5.00
3     gfds    item4
4     dfgh    item5   4.00
5     hgfd    item6
```

Comment: What expected result do you want? The first or the second result? You want something like the first instead sth like the second, or you are getting the first but you want the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), in order to combine results of multiple select queries. Since there are no chances of duplicates, between these multiple select queries, we can use `Union All`. We need to ensure that both the select queries are returning same number of column(s). Eventually we can sort the combined result by `ID` using `ORDER BY`:

```
(SELECT ID, 
       Name, 
       Prod AS Item, 
       Cost 
FROM red_table) 

UNION ALL 

(SELECT ID, 
       Title AS Name, 
       Item, 
       '' AS Cost
FROM blue_table) 

ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, name, prod as item,cost from red_tbl UNION ALL select id, title as name, item, NULL as cost  from blue_tbl
```

Change field name on select of 'prod' to 'item' in red table and 'title' to 'name' in blue table. Select null field which is not available in table (here cost field in blue table) because in union number of selected field must have same number.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use UNION operator

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 
UNION 
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

**Rules:**

Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns.The columns must also have similar data types. The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order